# Net SSH Expect print output

Tags: perl, ssh

My code as below

```
use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
            host => "$node_name",
            user => 'admin',
            timeout => 10,
            raw_pty => 1,
            );

$ssh->run_ssh() or die "SSH process couldn't start: $!";

$ssh->waitfor('password: ');

$ssh->send("$password");

$ssh->waitfor('mml> ');

@ls=$ssh->exec("$command");

print @ls;

#BREAK1: At this point remote device ask for "Press Enter to continue..." because output is more than one page..that is why below code

while ($ssh->waitfor('continue')) {
$line=$ssh->send("\n");
print $line;
}
```

I want to print all the output captured, however it prints only which is captured by `@ls=$ssh->exec("$command");` and it do not print anything which is captured by code below `BREAK1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perldoc of the module reccomends following when output is large:

```
 # When running a command that causes a huge output,
 # lets get the output line by line:
 $ssh->send("find /");   # using send() instead of exec()
 my $line;
 # returns the next line, removing it from the input stream:
 while ( defined ($line = $ssh->read_line()) ) {
     print $line . "\n";
 }
```

Also note that send() is not supposed to return anything, you should use read_line() or read_all(). [Module doc](http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod)

Comment: Hi, I tried the same and it works well for second page only (basically i have 5-6 pages of output )..It prints two page but did not print pages after second page....any help ?

Comment: I think you can try checking each line for 'continue' and if pattern is found send return feed again inside the while loop. Another way is to use the before() function after calling the waitfor('continue') in loop.

Comment: Oh god! finally it is done....do {
$ssh->send("\n");  
$line = $ssh->read_line();
push(@ls,"$line");
} while ($line!~/mml>/);

foreach (@ls) {
print "$_\n";
}

Answer (score 0):

add this `$ssh->exec("stty raw -echo");`

Comment: please put your code in a `code block` with the help of the ` character around your code (inline). For a code paragraph, add 4 spaces before the text of each line. Thanks!

Comment: Provide more information, tell the poster why you think this would solve their problem or what they're doing wrong.